# Daisy-Chaining 2 Drobo DAS's — Becomes 1 device or 2?

Tags: finder, drobo, daisychaining

I have a [Drobo 5Nt](http://www.drobo.com/storage-products/5d-5dt/) (5-disk direct-attached storage) which has two Thunderbolt 2 ports on the back.

I understand the two ports allow me to daisy-chain multiple Drobo devices together — so if I buy a second Drobo, will I effectively see one larger drive in my filesystem? or is it simply going to create two separate devices (attached through one port)?

**My System:**

- MacBook Pro (late 2016) with USB-C
- USB-C to Thunderbolt 2 connector
- Drobo 5Nt

*Note: I understand I may lose some performance daisy-chaining storage this way, but that is outside the scope of this discussion.*

Answer (score 0):

> I understand the two ports allow me to daisy-chain multiple Drobo
>   devices together — so if I buy a second Drobo, will I effectively see
>   one larger drive in my filesystem? or is it simply going to create two
>   separate devices (attached through one port)?

Looking at the official [Drobo documentation on daisy chaining](http://dashboardhelp.drobo.com/guide/230/en/5D_Connecting_Your_Drobo_5D_in_a_Daisy-chain.htm), there is no indication that multiple devices connected together would inherently form one large, single Drobo device. Unless utterly anything indicates otherwise, it seems each device is it’s own, single device.

[image: Image of a MacBook daisy chained to two Drobo devices and an external display.]